# find: using wildcard in -name pattern

Tags: shell, find, regular-expression, wildcards

I have a simple wrapper script to play videos, where my script tries to find subtitle file to a given video file (if it exists). Given video name, I am looking for same name, only ending in `.vtt` extension instead of video format extension:

```
#!/bin/sh

video_file="$1"

sub_file="$(/bin/find -name ${video_file%.*}.*.vtt)"

if [ -f "$sub_file" ] ; then
   echo "subtitles found: $sub_file"
else
   echo "subtitles not found"
fi
```

If multiple sub files exist, ie: `foo.en.vtt`, `foo.de.vtt`, I want to use the first one found.

The problem is the above script only works when zero or one matching `.vtt` files exist. If two exist, then `find` returns following error:

```
/bin/find: paths must precede expression: `2207-_-20220620.en.vtt'
/bin/find: possible unquoted pattern after predicate `-name'?
subtitles not found
```

The problem seems to be that find gets two parameters for the `-name` predicate. But I cannot quote the pattern `${video_file%.*}.*.vtt` because then the wildcard `*` would be interpreted literally.

I have tried using `-regex` predicate with same results

How can I achieve what I want in my script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote,

> But I cannot quote the pattern `${video_file%.*}.*.vtt` because then the wildcard `*` would be interpreted literally

I think that in this situation it's exactly what you need to do. Quoting the field stops the shell from applying it as a glob, but it allows `find` to see the wildcard characters in the filename pattern. (`find -name` understands wildcard patterns itself - see `man find` and search for the explanation for `-name` for details.)

As described in your question, let's assume that the video file is `foo.mp4` and there are two subtitles files `foo.de.vtt` and `foo.en.vtt`.

You can identify both of these with this snippet

```
video=foo.mp4
find . -name "${video_file%.*}.*.vtt" -print
```

And this outputs

```
./foo.de.vtt
./foo.en.vtt
```

You said that you wanted just the first one, so with a non-POSIX extension `-quit` you can grab just the first:

```
subtitles=$(find -name "${video_file%.*}.*.vtt" -print -quit)

echo "> $subtitles"
> ./foo.de.vtt
```

Note that `find` searches in directory order and therefore does not necessarily return results in sorted order. If you can guarantee matched file names do not contain newlines you could use `find … -print | sort | head -n1` to sort according to the current locale. (It's then also [POSIX conformant](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html).)